# REST API advice for beginner

Tags: php, android, rest, braintree

I'm pretty new in this part of programming so any help would be appreciated.

I've made an app and now I want to allow the user to buy via [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/). I have implemented it with help of some tutorials using [PHP SDK](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php), tested on phone using XAMPP and [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It works perfectly (generates token, makes a payment using [testing cards](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/testing-go-live/php)) but now I want to move it online. Just simply move that folder from XAMPP instalation folder somewhere online so I (and all other useres) don't need to use ngrok.

Actually, want to replace

```
    final String API_GET_TOKEN = "https:/smthng-random.ngrok.io/braintree/main.php";
    final String API_PAY = "http://smthng-random.ngrok.io//braintree/pay.php";
```

with

```
final String API_GET_TOKEN = "https:/WHATEVER/main.php";
final String API_GET_PAY = "https:/WHATEVER/pay.php";
```

so that can give me the same what I've got with xampp and ngrok.

Thanks in advance

btw: PHP is not my better side of programming so it would be great just to move those 2 files (main.php & pay.php) just like they are :) And I've just found that firebase might be option but just exploring for now :)

Comment: not 100% clear: you want to dynamicly change the actual string to 'whatever' (in adnroid?)? Or do you ask how to setup on a new server? Or how to move the files via php to a different (sub-) folder?

Comment: online server where i can import those php files and braintree php sdk :)

Comment: make an account on 000webhost.com go to the file manager of your site! and put your sdk and files there and access them withThe name of your site/folder/files

Comment: yes its free for a limited amount of time

Comment: Put it all public even of there's private key for braintree/paypal?

Answer (score 1):

I think your request is unclear - it's not REST API advice at all, it's about deploying an application to a live environment.

You have successfully installed your web development environment locally (XAMP, nginx) and now it's time to go *live*.

You basically need a Linux server capable of running, well, **a**pache **m**ysql, **p**hp (get where that X**AMP** comes from?)

This is only an overview, search how to do each of the topics I'll describe:
1. Find a host. (You should go to the shared, vps hostings if you're inexperienced, otherwise, there are **way better** hosts like linode, digital ocean and AWS, but those can be a little more challenging for beginners.
2. Buy a domain 
3. Point the domain's DNS to your host's IP address or NS
4. Now, upload those files you mentioned to the servers public folder. Servers public folders might differ, specially from shared / vps hostings to full-blown Linux instances. If you go the "cloud" way (digital ocean, etc) usually you'll drop the files at /var/www/html 
*You'll have to set up virtual hosts if you decide to go for the full blown Linux instances*
The files should be accessible now. Make sure versions are consistent between your machine and your servers.

Comment: Someone told me its an api so i was confused and decide to ask here about it. Thanks a lot